# Android Espresso onData strange behavior

Tags: android, functional-testing, android-espresso

I have an **Activity** with **ListView** (id: *android.R.id.list*). The **ListView** shows information from a custom adapter, and I want to use Espresso to click on a specific view in a specific item: I want to click the view with id *R.id.continueButton* in the item that shows information from the object *testOrder*.

My test is:

```
onData(is(sameAsOrder(testOrder)))
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.continueButton))
        .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
        .perform(click());
```

where *sameAsOrder()* is:

```
public static Matcher<Object> sameAsOrder(final Order order) {
    assertNotNull(order);
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, Order>(Order.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(Order myOrder) {
            return myOrder.getId().equals(order.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText(" with id '" + order.getId() + "'");
        }
    };
}
```

I run the tests on my device, but when I load my Order objects from a online server the click happens on the action bar menu, as if I run the Espresso command

```
openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
```

When using dummy data it clicks on the correct list item. Moreover, when using dummy data on the emulator it also clicks on the action bar menu.

If I remove the menu, the test passes without nothing being clicked (as far as I can tell...)

Does anybody have an ideia why that strange behavior happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The strange behavior has nothing to do with *onData()*. I am using action bar overlay mode. Due to difference on screen sizes from my device to the emulator, and due to different data being used to fill the list (dummy vs. loaded from server), sometimes the item that I want to click on is getting below the action bar. When Espresso tries to click on it, it clicks on the action bar...